# Soundcloud downloads not working

Tags: soundcloud

I have a RSS feed enabled for my podcast on soundcloud. The feed address is http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:76350597/sounds.rss

It works with no problem on podcast client apps. However, i usually provide a link for people to directly download the MP3 files from their browser.

So if my track is https://soundcloud.com/bschumor/bsc177-seja-pessego-saude-cosmeticos-higiene-b-podcast then my RSS feed throws me the following link:

feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/177753992-bschumor-bsc108-ate-que-eu-tentei-podcast.mp3

Usually clicking on it would have the browser playing it or downloading (depending on the browser) and right-clicking and "Saving as..." would allow a download. On mobile it would play directly, no soundcloud widget or app required.

For couple weeks at least, this is not working anymore. Clicking on such link would redirect people to a **feeds-tmp** domain, in this case

feeds-tmp.soundcloud.com/stream/177753992-bschumor-bsc108-ate-que-eu-tentei-podcast.mp3 and nothing happens.

Does anyone knows how to get a direct link to the MP3? Has soundcloud deactivated this on purpose?

Comment: You can directly download your track with this link: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/257223747/download?client_id=yourclientid